# Is it possible to set language for whole marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, language

I can set the language in settings for social studio. However, I could not find any setting link (language, locale, currency) for marketing cloud(journey builder, audience builder,automation studio,content builder, contact builder). Is it derived from sales force platform?

Answer (score 1):

Setting language for the platform is done under Administration > Business Unit  where you can set the Culture Code and locales for Date Format.

A User Account can also have it's own Culture Code

Culture Code is basically the user’s language. Marketing Cloud uses this value to tweak the user interface, such as the display of dates and times.